# Ubuntu 10.10 Gmail, Midori and GTK2 customization madness

Tags: browser, gmail, gui, ubuntu-10.10, gtk

This is related to my question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/257982/ubuntu-10-10-2nd-instance-of-firefox-does-not-obey-gtk2-customizations/258766#258766)

Midori is a browser that obeys my GTK2 customizations **EXCEPT** when it comes to Gmail. There are several parts to this conundrum:

1. Midori displays scrollbars on the left, with the specified width and arrows together on all sites **EXCEPT** Gmail. The Gmail look is exactly like the *Before* [screenshot](http://freeshells.co.uk/~cocorocara/images/Screenshot_Before.png) with scrollbars on the **right**, and the links at the top **black** and **underlined**.
2. Now from within Gmail if I click the "Web" link on the top left, it takes me to the Google search page but with scrollbars on the **LEFT**. The appearance otherwise is unchanged, with the links at the top **black** and **underlined**.
3. And now for the surprise: If I search by directly typing in the URL bar or by going to `google.com`, the UI is like the one in the *After* [screenshot](http://freeshells.co.uk/~cocorocara/images/Screenshot_After.png) with the scrollbar on the **LEFT**, top links in **blue**, the name displayed instead of "xxx@gmail.com", the gear-wheel for the options, etc.
4. From within this search page (with the *After* look), if I select "Gmail" from the top menu, it takes me back to the *Before* look, with scrollbars on the **right**, and the links at the top **black** and **underlined**.

So the question is why does this happen? Why doesn't Gmail follow the rules on one browser while it does on another? Why are there two different UIs for the same website on the same browser?

Comment: Scrollbar position can depend on the "direction" attribute of a page, and it is possible that the older navbar causes this _somehow_. (The navbar you see in screenshot #2 has been introduced fairly recently.) Try clearing cookies and/or the cache.

Comment: @grawity Nope. Clearing cookies and cache doesn't change anything. Its just the same. I think this question will be answered when we know why my Firefox started to display Gmail correctly once I synchronized my profiles.